# the winner of a grueling campaign

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

Does "a campaign" here refer to "a campaign of general election" - that it, the campaign includes Democratic, Republican and Independent campaigns.

> The Associated Press tweeted on Nov 8:
>
> JOE BIDEN DEFEATS PRESIDENT DONALD TRUMP
>
> The Associated Press declares Joe Biden **the winner of a grueling campaign** for the American presidency. He will lead a polarized nation through a historic collision of health, economic and social crises.

Comment: Yes. That is what it means in this case.

Comment: @NewPlanet We don't say **a campaign of general election**. The phrase is almost always **a general election campaign** although you could also refer to **a/the campaign for a general election**.